# What's the LibreOffice Writer equivalent to attaching a CSS file to an HTML document?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

Are there any built in styles that will make the whole document look different immediately, based on Headers and Lists, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Select the "flavour" of the document when creating it using one of the wizards (i don't want to say "style of the document" to avoid confusion with "character styles", "pages styles" and so on described by [ChrisThompson](https://superuser.com/questions/348058/whats-the-libreoffice-writer-equivalent-to-attaching-a-css-file-to-an-html-docu/348065#348065)); there are "elegant" and "business" 'styles' to select from.
2. Use the [Template Changer](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/templatechanger) extension to [associate a different template with a document that already exists](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Associate_template). Since styles are part of templates, you can modify the styling by assigning a template with different style definitins. By default, you can't reassign a different template in a simple way, but using the template changer extension, this functionality is added: some new entries in the `File` menu will appear to attach a new template.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. They are called styles. You can read up on them in the [documentation](http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Styles_and_Formatting).

There are several kinds of styles, such as paragraph styles and character styles. With a paragraph style you can change "Normal" to be a certain font/size, with tabs, indention, etc. Then, if you want to change it later, just modify the style and all the paragraphs in the document that are using that style will immediately change.

You can create other styles, name them anything you want, and configure lots of formatting options. Styles are a really great and very underutilized feature of many word processors. I encourage you to learn how they work and use them well.

Comment: Yes, I understand how to use styles but is there some sort of list of predefined styles that, when activated, will change the look of everything. Microsoft Word has the equivalent and they are named "Modern", "Elegant", etc..

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.